# How to prevent click release on different element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)

> If the button is pressed on one element and released on a different one, the event is fired on the most specific ancestor element that contained both.

Is there a way avoid that?

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/kossel-the-styleful/pen/oaPzNW) where I'm trying to simulate a modal with a dismiss mask

if works fine, however if you click on the "modal" (the red) and drag the mouse pointer to outside and release, the close function will be called. How can I avoid that behavior?

```js
function handleClose(e) {

  alert('close');
}

function handleModal(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(e)
}
```

```css
.modal {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.mask {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgb(123, 123, 123, 0.5);
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mask" onClick="handleClose(event);">
    <div class="modal" onClick="handleModal(event);"> fldsjfld </div>
  </div>
</div>
dfs df sdf asd fsadg
```

Comment: Better to post your code here as a runnable snippet.

Comment: oh let me try to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onmousedown` event listenner instead of `onclick`.
By using the `onmousedown`, the function will run once you click and not when you release the click.

---

Check YOUR updated codepen [HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxOREZ)

and here's a working snippet:

```js
function handleClose(e) {

  alert('close');
}

function handleModal(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(e)
}
```

```css
.modal {
  height: 2000px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.mask {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgb(123, 123, 123, 0.5);
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mask" onmousedown="handleClose(event);">
    <div class="modal" onmousedown="handleModal(event);"> fldsjfld </div>
  </div>
</div>
dfs df sdf asd fsadg
```

Comment: Let me know if this did it for you. Check the codepen included.

Comment: worked fine for me. do you know a nicer way to do without the needing of stopPropagation() on the modal?